# Wordpress Blog system display setup problem

Tags: wordpress

I had followed all the installation step on the wordpress.org  and working  fine on the host machine . Everything including image ,flash, text can be display on the Host pc. However, when i try to connect the hose via local IP(eg.192.168.0.112) from another LAN PC. In come out only shows words On the local PC. No image no flash at all..
Can't find any info on the web anyone who know how to fix it  please help

Comment: Couple suggestions: a. This may be a better question on ServerFault -- http://serverfault.com b. Can you connect to 192.168.0.112 on your host machine (Instead of localhost)? c. What web server are you using? Please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. -_- very simple question

it is just because the wordpress engine try to load CSS  from Localhost/wordpress/.../default.css 
it should be load from the host machine. which is /192.168.0.112/wordpress/.../default.css

so go the the admin setting

type in your wordpress address and site address  with ur local ip

it should be working